# How to push data into more objects with the same properties

Tags: angularjs

I try to learn angularjs. I have this array with objects:

```
ctrl.list = [
  {
    name: 'Superman',
    location: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'Batman',
    location: 'Wayne Manor'
  }
];
```

And I want to add more heros inside, but I don't know how.
I was thinking of this way:

```
ctrl.addHero = function(prop, value) {
  ctrl.list.push({prop: value});
};
```

But in this way I add only one prop each time.

Comment: create a object. `hero: { name: '', location:''}` then u can keep adding new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
ctrl.addHero = function(name, location) { 
    ctrl.list.push({name: name, location: location});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of heros and concatenate with the list.

Hero will be : `{'name': someName, 'location':somewhere}`
So

```
ctrl.addHeros = function(heros) {
  ctrl.list = ctrl.list.concat(heros);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ctrl.addHero = function (name, location){
var hero = new Object();
hero.name = name
hero.location = location;

ctrl.list.push (hero);
}
```